# Variable initialized with garbage value in copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, garbage

In my comp sci class we are making a vector class. I am stuck because my copy constructor is initializing my 'limit' variable with a garbage value and I dont understand why.

Here is my main:

```
myStringVector v1 {"a", "b", "c"};
std::cout << "make it here?" << std::endl;
myStringVector v2 = v1;
std::cout << v1[0] << v1[1] << v1[2] << std::endl;
std::cout << v2[0] << v2[1] << v2[2] << std::endl;
assert(v1 == v2);
std::cout << "Passed copy ctor" << std::endl;
```

Here is the constructor that takes an initializer_list

```
myStringVector::myStringVector(std::initializer_list<myString> list){
   this->reserve(list.size());
   for(int i = 0; i < limit-1; i++){
     construct(first+i, list.begin()[i]);
   }
}
```

Here is the copy constructor

```
myStringVector::myStringVector(const myStringVector& data){
  reserve((data.limit)-1);
  for(int i = 0; i < data.limit-1; i++){
    construct(&first+i, data.first+i);
  }
}
```

Here is what reserve looks like

```
void myStringVector::reserve(int n){
  this->first = allocate<myString>(n);
  this->last = first+n;
  this->limit = n+1;
}
```

My assertion in main is failing because I overloaded the == operator to first check if the limits are equal. If they are not, the function returns false. The function continues after that, but it is failing the assertion because I am getting my v1 to be 4, which is correct, and then my v2 is some large number that doesn't make sense.

I've tried rewriting my copy constructor to directly initialize the members of the class without using reserve and it still doesn't work. It is still assigning garbage values to limit. The rest of it is working fine.

Here is what main is outputting...

make it here?

abc

abc

4 7500072

Assertion failed: v1 == v2, file myCodeTres.cpp, line 58

I feel like I've tried everything I can think of to try and fix this but nothings working. Any advice for me?

Thanks.

Update: these are the compiler error I get when I leave the ampersand out.

In file included from myCodeTres.cpp:20:
myMemory.hpp: In instantiation of 'T* construct(T*, Args&& ...) [with T = myString; Args = {myString*}]':
myStringVector.cpp:25:36:   required from here
myMemory.hpp:61:10: error: no matching function for call to 'myString::myString(myString*)'
61 |   return new (p) T(std::forward(args)...);
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**then there are some weird errors that are in blue on the compiler screen **

In file included from myCodeTres.cpp:23:
myString.cpp:42:1: note: candidate: 'myString::myString(myString&&)'
42 | myString::myString(myString&& move) : strLength(strlen(move.stringVar)) //move constructor to move contents from
| ^~~~~~~~
myString.cpp:42:31: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'myString*' to 'myString&&'
42 | myString::myString(myString&& move) : strLength(strlen(move.stringVar)) //move constructor to move contents from
|                    ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
myString.cpp:32:1: note: candidate: 'myString::myString(const myString&)'
32 | myString::myString(const myString& strToCpy) : strLength(strlen(strToCpy.stringVar)) //copy constructor that removes old elements
| ^~~~~~~~
myString.cpp:32:36: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'myString*' to 'const myString&'
32 | myString::myString(const myString& strToCpy) : strLength(strlen(strToCpy.stringVar)) //copy constructor that removes old elements
|                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
In file included from myCodeTres.cpp:23:
myString.cpp:23:1: note: candidate: 'myString::myString(const char*, std::size_t)'
23 | myString::myString(const char* cPnt, std::size_t size) : strLength(size) //constructor to take a size and const ptr to char
| ^~~~~~~~
myString.cpp:23:1: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
myString.cpp:14:1: note: candidate: 'myString::myString(const char*)'
14 | myString::myString(const char* cPnt) : strLength(strlen(cPnt)) //constructor to initialize to a given const ptr to char.
| ^~~~~~~~
myString.cpp:14:32: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'myString*' to 'const char*'
14 | myString::myString(const char* cPnt) : strLength(strlen(cPnt)) //constructor to initialize to a given const ptr to char.
|                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
myString.cpp:8:1: note: candidate: 'myString::myString()'
8 | myString::myString() //default constructor: initializes empty string.
| ^~~~~~~~
myString.cpp:8:1: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided

update: whole class definition

```
 #ifndef MYSTRINGVECTOR_HPP
 #define MYSTRINGVECTOR_HPP

  #include "myString.hpp"
  #include <initializer_list>

  class myStringVector{
  private:
  myString *first, *last;
  int limit = 0;
  public:
  void reserve(int); //allocate memory at 'first' for n myString's
  myStringVector(); //call to reserve(0)
  myStringVector(std::initializer_list<myString>);
  myStringVector(const myStringVector&);
  bool empty();
  bool operator==(const myStringVector&);
  myString operator[](int);
  int getSize() const;
};
```

#endif //MYSTRINGVECTOR_HPP_INCLUDED

.cpp file

```
#include "myStringVector.hpp"
#include "myMemory.hpp"
#include <initializer_list>

void myStringVector::reserve(int n){
  this->first = allocate<myString>(n);
  this->last = first+n;
  this->limit = n+1;
}

myStringVector::myStringVector(){
 this->reserve(0);
 } 

 myStringVector::myStringVector(std::initializer_list<myString> list){
 this->reserve(list.size());
 for(int i = 0; i < limit-1; i++){
  construct(first+i, list.begin()[i]);
 }
 }

myStringVector::myStringVector(const myStringVector& data){
 reserve((data.limit)-1);
  for(int i = 0; i < data.limit-1; i++){
    construct(first+i, data.first+i);
 }
}

bool myStringVector::empty(){
  return (limit-1 == 0);
}

 bool myStringVector::operator==(const myStringVector& data){
 std::cout << limit << " " << data.limit << std::endl;
  if(this->limit != data.limit)
   return 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++){
    if(*(first+i) != *(data.first+i))
      return 0;
  }
 return 1;
}

myString myStringVector::operator[](int index){
  return *(first+index);
}

int myStringVector::getSize() const{
  return limit-1;
}
```

formatting is a bit off because uploading code to stackoverflow is tedious as can be.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I think you may have another problem: in one place you have `for(int i = 0; i < limit-1; i++)` and in another `for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++)`. I don't understand why you added 1 to `limit` in the first place; it seems to serve no other purpose than as an invitation to make mistakes. It's also a mystery what the purpose of `last` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple error, in your copy constructor

```
construct(&first+i, data.first+i);
```

should be

```
construct(first+i, data.first+i);
```

**EDIT**

This from the initializer list constructor works.

```
construct(first+i, list.begin()[i]);
```

Now think carefully about the types here. The first argument is simple enough, it's a pointer to myString i.e. `myString*`. The second is a little more complicated because you have to understand `std::initializer_list` but if you follow it through it's a const reference to myString, i.e. `const myString&`. Now this is fine because `construct` is defined like this

```
template <class T>
void construct(T* first, const T& second);
```

i.e. for some type `T` it's first argument is a pointer to that type, and it's second argument is a const reference to that type.

Now look at the types for the second use of `construct` (the one that doesn't compile)

```
construct(first+i, data.first+i);
```

The first argument is `myString*` and the second argument is `const myString*`. Two pointers! This is why it doesn't compile! Your solution was to add an extra pointer to the first argument. The types of

```
construct(&first+i, data.first+i);
```

are `myString**` and `const myString*`. That compiles because you have a double pointer on the left and a single pointer on the right but it means that you are constructing pointers to myString not myString objects, and that is not what you want.

What you should have done is **remove** the pointer from the second argument, not add an extra pointer to the first argument. In other words the correct code is this

```
construct(first+i, data.first[i]);
```

Now the types are `myString*` for the first and `const myString&` for the second argument. Exactly the same as in the other constructor.

Try that change and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Good catch, though that was [supposed to be fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65046507/conversion-problem-with-stdinitializer-listclass-object-in-c#comment114996365_65046507) by now.

Comment: @dxiv It wont let me not have the ampersand. This is another problem. It acts like Im passing it a regular myString when I don't have the ampersand. And construct isn't even where the problem lies. It is not initializing LIMIT correctly which is in reserve. Thats what I was asking.

Comment: @dxiv As you can see it is having no problem constructing the vector with the correct values as the output of both v1 and v2 are a b and c. It is the limit that is the problem. Please re-evaluate my question with the limit in mind, I still have not figured out why it wont initialize limit correctly.

Comment: @JesseWood What error do you see when you use the ampersand? As you can see from the code you have posted you did not need the ampersand in the other constructor you wrote. And the ampersand is incorrect. There seems to be some issue here which isn't apparent from the code you have posted.

Comment: @john yes, I believe there is a big underlying problem because the compiler tells me I cannot use a myString as an argument when I leave the ampersand out. But as you said, in the other constructor, construct takes first without the ampersand no problem. Any ideas why the behavior would be changing like that?

Comment: @JesseWood Please quote the **exact** error you get. The wording may give clues to the problem that aren't apparent to you. Plus I think we need to see the whole class definition, please include that in the question.

Comment: @john sorry, I initially forgot the class definition. Im adding it now!

Comment: So I *think* I have a explanation for the ampersand issue. It's guess work because I don't see the definition of `construct`. And it may or may not be your real problem, but I think you should try the fix I suggest and see how things are. It's quite lengthy so I'm going to edit it into my answer above. Stay tuned.

Comment: @JesseWood OK answer updated. I feel fairly confident because I think what it happening is that you are setting `limit` but then the incorrect call to `construct` that I've now fixed is trashing the value of `limit` and that explains the results you see.

Comment: @John thank you so much. I’m at work currently but when I get home I will try your code and update you.

Comment: @john Amazing explanation! Worked perfectly.

Comment: @JesseWood Glad it works. I realised after I'd written it that my explanation is not quite correct. The definition of `construct` I used is out of date. `construct` changed in C++11, but the definition I used is applicable to the way you are using it, so the explanation is still valid.